# String Manipulation Recursive Function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, recursion

Struggling with implementing a recursive transformation function that would remove consecutive duplicate letters from string...

for e.g `"abbabcc" => "aabcc"` (on first pass, remove `"bb"`)

for e.g `"aabcc" => "bcc"` (on second pass, remove `"aa"`)

and then recursively call itself till the final reduction is something like `"abbabcc" => "b"`

```
def transformations(J):
    if len(J) == 1:
        return J
    front_part = ""
    back_part = ""
    if J[0] == J[1]:
        back_part += J[2:]
        return transformations(back_part)
    else: 
        front_part += J[0]
        back_part += J[1:]
        return front_part + transformations(back_part)

assert transformations("ab") == "ab"
assert transformations("aba") == "aba"
assert transformations("abc") == "abc"
assert transformations("aabbbccaaba") == "a"


assert transformations("abba") == "" 
# "abba" should return "aa" on first pass then return empty string 
# on second pass, but right now it returns "aa" and stops there
```

right now, the above algorithm works for most inputs except ones with double consecutives in the middle that result in another double consecutive after removal of the first consecutive, e.g `("abba")`

I need a base if case that accounts for this but I can't figure one out, is there something wrong with my algorithm?

Comment: Just looking at your input string, each string will require at least one separation letter.  are you looking to remove all duplicates in the first pass and then remove newly found duplicates in your second pass?.  Eg: abbabcc => aab => b

Comment: im looking to remove from left to right, so something like abbabcc ==> aabcc ==> bcc ==> b

Comment: Ok understand.  There's several ways to do it.  Are you familiar with regex?

Comment: thanks! i am familiar with regex but i'm trying to solve it with recursion

Comment: `aabbbccaaba` -> `bbbccaaba`-> `bccaaba`-> `baaba` -> `bba` -> `a` ?

Comment: thats true! edited, now just have to figure out why its not working for "abba"

Comment: you need to do the transform until `input == output`. not until you run out of length.

Comment: Ah apologies misread the questions. I can see you are being careful about an endless recursion, however when looking at recursion problems, it's important to know when or what your exit condition more generally to ensure you are correctly returning. In your case it seems `input == output` is the exit condition as @BhathiyaPerera mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform until `input == result`. When `input == result` that means it can no longer transformed. See below for changes.

```
def transformations(J):
    if len(J) <= 1: # I made it less than or equal
        return J
    front_part = ""
    back_part = ""
    if J[0] == J[1]:
        back_part = J[2:]
        return transformations(back_part)
    else: 
        front_part = J[0]
        back_part = J[1:]
        # See below
        result =  front_part + transformations(back_part)
        # If it's same we have done all transformations.
        if result == J:
            return result
        else: # try to perform more transformations
            return transformations(result)

tests = [
    ["abba", ""],
    ["ab", "ab"],
    ["aba", "aba"],
    ["aabbbccaaba", "a"]
]

for inp, expected in tests:
    actual = transformations(inp)
    print("trans(%s) == %s" % (inp, actual), "Test Passed =", actual == expected)
```

This will result in

```
trans(abba) ==  Test Passed = True
trans(ab) == ab Test Passed = True
trans(aba) == aba Test Passed = True
trans(aabbbccaaba) == a Test Passed = True
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question above and as highlighted in the comment by @Bhathiya Perera doing recursive calls requires an exit condition, firstly so your code doesn't run forever but also to define a satisfactory return.

In your case the exit condition would be that the string contains no more duplicates which can be extended to, I cannot remove any more characters or that the input_string = output_string.

A further comment would be that if your exit condition is well defined you can use for loops without worrying about an endless call to the function.

```
def remove_adjacent_duplicates(input_string): 
    '''
    Function removes adjacent duplicates recursively
    '''
    string_length = len(input_string)
    # If length of string is 1 or 0 then there are no duplicates present
    if string_length == 0 or string_length == 1: 
        return input_string 

    # Iterate through the string to remove all duplicates present in first pass
    # Note that the range goes from 1 -> len-1 to avoid boundary errors
    for i in range(1, string_length - 1):
        if input_string[i-1] == input_string[i]:
            # Remove duplicates by slicing the string around the duplicates
            new_string = input_string[:i - 1] + input_string[i + 1:]
            print new_string

    if new_string == input_string:
        #  Define the exit condition 
        return input_string
    else:
        # Recursive call if there have been duplicate removals
        # This will do a final call to ensure no more duplicates remain 
        return remove_adjacent_duplicates(new_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Advent of Code, right? :-) How about

```
while True:
    backup = input
    for letter in string.ascii_lowercase: input = input.replace(letter * 2, '')
    if backup == input: break
```

?